# How to Pass some Predefined Set values into button click on success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a Simple CRUD Application using Bootstrap Model ,jquery and ASP.NET.In my Application there are 5 centres for which we have to perform these operations so lot's of same code replication is there .I want to optimize the code but got stuck in very unusual situation, i completely know what is the problem but not able to find the solution

index.cshtml:

```
<input type="button" name="Coloumbus" value="coloumbus" onclick="loaddata('Coloumbus')"/>
<input type="button" name="Milwaukee" value="Milwaukee" onclick="loaddata('Milwaukee')"/>
```

JQuery Code :

```
function loaddata(TeamParameter)
{

    if(TeamParameter=='coloumbus')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/listall",
            type: "GET",
            data: 'TeamParameter='+TeamParameter,
            contentType: "application/json ;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var html = '';
                $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.MgrCode + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.SSN_NO + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.jcp_id + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.First_Name + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Last_Name + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.EmailAddress + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Admin_Level + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp1 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp2 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp3 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp4 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp5 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Grp6 + '</td>';
                    html += '<td><input type="button"  value="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="getbyIDColoumbus(' + item.MgrCode + ')" /> &nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteColoumbus(' + item.MgrCode + ')" /> </td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                });
            }
        });
    }
    if(TeamParameter=='Milwaukee')
    {
    }
```

i want to pass one more set parameter like TeamParameter on EDit and delete html row in success call back so that i could retreive on another function but i am not able to do it, i tried  to Pass only string values also .Can anyone help me,i want to just pass one more parameter with item.mgrcode like TeamParameter so that i could retreive the value from some other function

```
html += '<td><input type="button"  value="Edit" class="btn btn-sm        btn-success" onclick="getbyIDColoumbus(' + item.MgrCode + ')" /> &nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteColoumbus(' + item.MgrCode + ')" /> </td>';
```

Comment: No,that's a typing mistake @satpal

Comment: @Satpal ...can you help me on this

Comment: Try this one `"getbyIDColoumbus(' + item.MgrCode + ',\'' + TeamParameter +'\')"`

Comment: i tried this @satpal,but the value null is coming into the Receiving function ,i want to set the value of this parameter to coloumbus and want to receive from other end

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/ywvtr0jt/, Also note JavaScript is case sensitive `"Coloumbus" !== "coloumbus"`